# R : How to use apply in this case to speed up the function?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, distance, r-sf

I'm trying to calculate the distance between points and the closest polygon for each point. I'm currently using the function st_distance (library sf), that seems the fastest method to do that. But it's still taking a lot of time. 
That's why I want to change the loop for that I'm using into an apply procedure or in a way to do this faster. Could somebody help me to do that please ?
Thanks !

```
## Importation of shapefiles
# library(rgdal)
# pathToShp = "J:/shp_files/"
# points = readOGR(dsn = pathToShp, layer="points_2154", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)   #Points in EPSG 2154 Lambert
# polygons = readOGR(dsn = pathToShp, layer="polygons_2154", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)   #Polygons

library(sf)
# points_sf = st_as_sf(points)
# polygons_sf = st_as_sf(polygons)

## Search the closest polygon for each point
point_polygon <- c()
point_polygon = st_join(points_sf, polygons_sf, join = st_nearest_feature)     # ID of the closest polygon for each point

## Distance between each point and the closest polygon
dist_sf <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(points_sf)) {
  dist_sf[i] = st_distance(points_sf[i,], 
                           polygons_sf[polygons_sf$ID == point_polygon$ID[i], ], 
                           by_element = TRUE)    
}
```

You should obtain :

```
dist_sf
# [1] 514830.0 260656.0 260647.7 260653.5 262053.6
```

#### Data

```
points_sf <- structure(list(field_1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), adresse = c("6 RUE DES VIGNES, 40140 SOUSTONS, France", 
"22 RUE DE PARIS, 03000 MOULINS, France", "5 RUE REGNAUDIN, 03000 MOULINS, France", 
"31 RUE DE PARIS, 03000 MOULINS, France", "15 RUE DES RAMIERS, 85360 LA TRANCHE SUR MER, France"
), latitude = c(43.75395, 46.56875, 46.56893, 46.56873, 46.35638
), longitude = c(-1.31277, 3.330296, 3.330394, 3.330224, -1.470842
), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(352768.516216819, 6304476.86420524
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(725298.307259582, 
6607688.02981763), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(725305.729670888, 
6607708.05130113), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(725292.801896427, 
6607685.78563239), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(356412.817813797, 
6593779.89675049), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 352768.516216819, 
ymin = 6304476.86420524, xmax = 725305.729670888, ymax = 6607708.05130113
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, 
    proj4string = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(field_1 = NA_integer_, 
adresse = NA_integer_, latitude = NA_integer_, longitude = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))

polygons_sf <- structure(list(ID = c("M1204300", "E6490620", "E4240850"), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(list(structure(c(533957.599997006, 534047.299997008, 
    534171.89999701, 534191.69999701, 534226.099997011, 534270.599997012, 
    534325.099997013, 534369.799997014, 534449.399997015, 534549.199997017, 
    534674.099997019, 534924.099997023, 535084.299997026, 535174.199997028, 
    535239.099997029, 535293.89999703, 535323.599997031, 6786523.09989417, 
    6786492.39989417, 6786461.39989417, 6786436.19989417, 6786370.99989417, 
    6786305.69989417, 6786255.19989417, 6786219.89989417, 6786184.19989417, 
    6786163.39989417, 6786162.39989417, 6786185.29989417, 6786218.89989417, 
    6786218.19989417, 6786207.69989417, 6786182.19989417, 6786156.99989417
    ), .Dim = c(17L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "MULTILINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(608743.099998312, 608792.899998313, 
    608827.799998314, 608847.799998314, 608867.999998314, 608918.699998315, 
    608974.499998316, 609015.299998317, 609071.299998318, 609086.499998318, 
    609106.399998319, 609156.19999832, 609181.59999832, 609197.09999832, 
    609202.299998321, 609217.599998321, 609257.999998322, 609273.299998322, 
    609324.099998323, 609354.699998323, 7003205.49989546, 7003185.09989545, 
    7003164.79989545, 7003169.69989546, 7003194.49989546, 7003278.99989546, 
    7003378.49989546, 7003478.09989546, 7003597.59989546, 7003623.39989546, 
    7003618.29989546, 7003592.89989546, 7003642.59989546, 7003702.49989546, 
    7003732.39989546, 7003767.29989546, 7003816.89989546, 7003856.79989546, 
    7003946.29989546, 7004020.99989546), .Dim = c(20L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "MULTILINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(669193.399999424, 
    669183.499999424, 669153.399999423, 669097.999999422, 669077.999999422, 
    669048.599999421, 7097101.79989609, 7097111.89989609, 7097102.09989609, 
    7097047.59989609, 7097052.79989609, 7097123.99989609), .Dim = c(6L, 
    2L)), structure(c(669048.599999421, 669022.899999421, 668953.19999942, 
    668888.899999418, 668854.499999418, 668809.899999417, 668790.299999417, 
    668740.899999416, 668721.199999415, 668656.799999414, 668637.199999414, 
    668618.099999413, 7097123.99989609, 7097149.19989609, 7097189.79989609, 
    7097265.29989609, 7097340.49989609, 7097385.89989609, 7097430.99989609, 
    7097496.39989609, 7097532.59989609, 7097598.09989609, 7097653.1998961, 
    7097758.39989609), .Dim = c(12L, 2L)), structure(c(668618.099999413, 
    668598.799999413, 668553.799999412, 668519.299999411, 668435.09999941, 
    668335.899999408, 668159.599999405, 7097758.39989609, 7097833.49989609, 
    7097949.7998961, 7098010.0998961, 7098095.7998961, 7098191.4998961, 
    7098459.3998961), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "MULTILINESTRING", 
    "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTILINESTRING", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 533957.599997006, 
ymin = 6786156.99989417, xmax = 669193.399999424, ymax = 7098459.3998961
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, 
    proj4string = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 0:2, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(ID = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
apply(st_distance(points_sf, polygons_sf), 1, min)
```

seems to be the fastest option. Though a native sf version is not much slower.
See below for the actual timings

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
    loop = {
        point_polygon = st_join(points_sf, polygons_sf, join = st_nearest_feature)
        ## Distance between each point and the closest polygon
        dist_sf <- c()
        for (i in 1:nrow(points_sf)) {
            dist_sf[i] = st_distance(points_sf[i,], 
                                     polygons_sf[polygons_sf$ID == point_polygon$ID[i], ], 
                                     by_element = TRUE)    
        }
    },
    apply = { apply(st_distance(points_sf, polygons_sf), 1, min) },
    native = {
        polys = polygons_sf[st_nearest_feature(points_sf, polygons_sf), ]
        st_length(st_nearest_points(points_sf, polys, pairwise = TRUE))
    },
    dt = {
        dist = as.data.table(st_distance(points_sf, polygons_sf))
        dist[, pmin(V1, V2, V3)]
    },
    times = 10
)


Unit: milliseconds
   expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval  cld
   loop 29.2660 30.36030 32.092494 30.95950 32.97390 42.5732   100    d
  apply  2.7579  2.90365  3.124069  2.96670  3.20515  5.0635   100 a   
 native  3.9875  4.13340  4.566414  4.24310  4.55095 11.9232   100   c 
     dt  3.4089  3.57920  3.838198  3.66055  3.93795  8.6983   100  b
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
In reality, polygons_sf doesn't have only 3 elements, but more than 100,000. I tried to run your code with all the polygons and the native solution seems faster

```r
Unit: seconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
   loop  7.086761  8.287012  9.023580  8.825570  9.646178 11.59616    10  a 
  apply 40.170422 41.481090 42.398297 42.048745 42.562616 46.17528    10   b
 native  6.795684  6.931117  7.840289  7.867703  8.146455 10.64996    10  a 
```

Comment: I've update my answer to include a solution with **data.table**. Maybe that scales better in your real-world scenario?

Comment: @yaki, I'm curious, how does the data.table solution compare to the rest with your data sets?